# Seeking Research tips: approach to researching homework and classwork tasks

Tags: research-process

I am a teacher and wants to look onto a case of my students failing to follow up on homework and classwork tasks. I want to study the fact and issues regarding their failure in completing their homework and its impact on academic achievement.

Can that be possible?
Any research tips, probably an action research for a small group of students.

I seek your wisdom and would be very grateful.

Comment: Could you give an example of "failing to follow up on homework tasks". By "completing" do you mean that students to not respect the deadline for assignments? As for advice, I tell a student who doesn't work hard that they're the ones who need to pass their exam, not me.

Answer (score 1):

You're entering the terrain of scholarship of teaching learning and assessment.

You can consider reflexivity and if ethics clearance permits, combine reflexivity with action research.

Whichever approach you take, engage with the school's ethics committee.

---

Possible pointers:
[Mihlon, J. (2017). Emerging Pathways: A Teacher/Researcher's Reflexive Journey Implementing Literacy-Based Science Interventions With Adolescent English Language Learners.](https://digitalcommons.nl.edu/diss/235/)

[Miller, D. L., & Kelley, M. L. (1991). Interventions for improving homework performance: A critical review. *School Psychology Quarterly*, 6(3), 174.](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/1992-14598-001)

[Coulter, F. (1979). Homework: A neglected research area. *British Educational Research Journal*, 5(1), 21-33.](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/0141192790050103)

[Rosenbaum, E. (1968). The Reflexive Verb Story: An Experience Unit. *Die Unterrichtspraxis/Teaching German*, 1(1), 23-26.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3529882)

[McElearney, P. (2023). A performative and dialogic approach to teach group roles, group conflict, and conflict management styles. *Communication Teacher*, 37(3), 227-234.](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/17404622.2023.2168714)